# Number of nonnegative integer solutions for $x_1+3x_2=100$ using Generating Functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I am struggling with the following problem and I was hoping somebody could help me.

Solve by applying the convolution formula for generating functions:
How many nonnegative integer solutions are there for $x_1 + 3x_2 = 100$?

I've been getting really high numbers in my attempts so far and there's no way that they are correct. If someone can help me get started that would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is my work so far which is giving me the answer $176851$ solutions which I'm sure is wrong.

$G(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+...)$
$G(x)=\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)}\right)\left(\frac{1}{(1-x^3)}\right)$

$a_n=1$ and

$b_n=\binom{n+2}{2}$

Then I'm finding the coefficient of $x^{100}$ from the convolution formula.

Comment: You start by finding the generating function. Did you get that far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, I think I have the generating function figured out. I'm using $G(x) = (1+x^2+x^3+x^4...)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+...)$.

Comment: By inspection, there are $34$ solutions.  Since $x_1, x_2$ must be nonnegative, $x_1 = 100 - 3x_2 \implies x_2  \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, 33\}$.

Comment: That's the same number of solutions I was thinking also. For some reason I cannot get my convolution to produce the same value.

Comment: Well, for one thing, your formula for $b_n$ is incorrect.  Can you see why?

Comment: No I am not sure what is wrong with that. I thought that was correct.